# Can't seem to find the correct syntax to create a Word doc

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

I'm looking to make a basic console app that creates a new Word document, adds text to it, and then saves it to file. At first I was attempting to use the Docx nuget package but I read somewhere that that may not be usable for free anymore. Trying to use that package I was getting a file not found error when attempting to create a new Docx file from scratch, and I'm still getting the same error when trying the code below using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` as well. Every online solution I've found returns that same error so I'm not sure if my issue lies in my references or perhaps file access in general. Thanks for the help in advance.

Error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Word.Application app = new Word.Application();

        Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Add();

        Word.Paragraph newParagraph;

        newParagraph = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
        newParagraph.Range.Text = "Document Creation Successful";

        doc.SaveAs2("test.docx");
        doc.Close();
        app.Quit();
    }
```

Project File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Document_Generation</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Word.dll">
      <Guid>00020905-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>8</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>7</VersionMinor>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocX" Version="1.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing Assembly called `Office.dll`. You can register it in GAC, if you want. Or you need to add reference to the project just like you have it for `word`.  Although, you have COM reference, I use regular DLL reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll`

Comment: The Office. libraries cannot be downloaded and used. The Office application(s) ***must*** be installed on the machine where the code is running. Installation will correctly register the libraries in the Registry. It will also install the .NET ***PIAs*** in the GAC. Execution of Office "interop" code relies on being able to run the applications. If you want to create documents without the Office applications being installed, look at Office Open XML and the Open XML SDK.

Comment: I do have word installed, but I read somewhere that when I install it I'm supposed to choose an option to add developer dependencies to the machine. Probably didn't do that, I think that's why I don't have the dll.

Answer (score 0):

You must add two Office interop files to the project references:

1. The core Office namespace is represented by the `Office.dll` library. This is a Microsoft Office Object Library that provides shared functionality.
2. The Word object model represented by the `Microsoft.Office.Word.dll` library.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Document_Generation</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Word.dll">
      <Guid>00020905-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>8</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>7</VersionMinor>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
    </COMReference>

    <COMReference Include="office.dll">
      <Guid>2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>8</VersionMinor>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

As an example, you may try to create a sample .Net framework based console application and try to add a COM reference to Word. Then you can observe the required references added (where you can also grab the required interop files).

You can read more about Office Interop assemblies on the [Office primary interop assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies?view=vs-2019) page.

Answer (score -2):

If you are making this in Visual Studio (which I would recommend) I would do something like (change directory and text however you like) :

```
File.Create("C:/test.docx").Dispose();
File.AppendAllText("D:/test.docx", "test text");
```

Comment: This does not answer the question